# Getting twitch channel feed forbidden

Tags: php, api, curl, twitch

As per the API: https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/v3_resources/channel_feed.md#get-feedchannelposts

I have tried using PHP and cUrl to get the latest channel feed comments. This is the URL I am polling:

```
https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/feed/:username/posts
```

Obviously with :username as my actual username. I am also passing:

```
"oauth_token" => "[MY OAUTH TOKEN]"
```

I know that this procedure normally works because I am using it to get normal info about the channel and followers info. Though trying it with the feed posts I get this message back (after JSON decoding it):

```
Array
(
    [error] => Forbidden
    [status] => 403
    [message] => Channel feed is disabled
)
```

When I set up the authorization for the account using oauth I included the following scope for allows:

```
user_read user_blocks_edit user_blocks_read user_follows_edit channel_read channel_editor channel_commercial channel_stream channel_subscriptions user_subscriptions channel_check_subscription chat_login channel_feed_read channel_feed_edit
```

As far as I know that is everything so not sure why it's coming up as forbidden, and as I mentioned I am using other parts of the API so not sure whats wrong here... Any ideas or help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am by no means an expert on twitch's API but I'll give it a shot. Looking through their github documentation it shows [3 ways of sending access token for authentication.](https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/authentication.md#authenticated-api-requests)

Is it possible you're sending the token in the HTTP body? It explicitly states that this won't work with `GET` and `DELETE` methods, which could be giving you an error when trying to `GET` channel feed posts. Hope this helps.

**EDIT:** Yousimply don't have channel feed enabled on your account. It's currently opt-in because it's in beta. See: http://help.twitch.tv/customer/portal/articles/2377877-how-to-use-channel-feed

Comment: Hi T Martin thanks for your response! Well I have tried polling this URL https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/:channel with the same post data and it returns all of the info fine. So don't think it could be that :(

Comment: Hmm let's see. Could it possibly be that the channel you're using simply doesn't have the channel feed beta enabled? See this link if you haven't already: http://help.twitch.tv/customer/portal/articles/2377877-how-to-use-channel-feed

Comment: Oh my goodness you're a hero! thank you I totally missed that :)

Comment: Would you mind changing your answer to the answer that answered it? Lol what a sentence...